# Open the Lock - BFS Application

Tags: java, algorithm, queue, breadth-first-search

I have just learned the BFS algorithm and I am trying to apply the BFS algorithm to solve the leetcode problem here [Open the Lock](https://leetcode.com/problems/open-the-lock/)

My algorithm works for some usecases and outputs a wrong answer for the others. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

```
    class Solution {
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    HashSet<String> deads = new HashSet<String>();
    public int openLock(String[] deadends, String target) {
        for(int i  = 0; i < deadends.length; i++){
            deads.add(deadends[i]);
        }
        if(deads.contains("0000"))return -1;
        int level  = bfs("0000", target);
        return level;
    
    }
public int bfs(String start, String target){
        int level  = 0;
        queue.add(start); // add the start to the queue
        deads.add(start);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            int groupSize = queue.size();
            while(groupSize >0){
                String current = queue.poll();
                if(current.equals(target)) return level;
                for(int i  = 0; i < current.length(); i++){
                    char c = current.charAt(i);
                    char temp  = c;
                    if( c == '9'){
                        c = '0';
                        temp  = c;
                    }else{
                        c++;
                    }
                    String upString = current.substring(0, i) + c + current.substring(i + 1);
                    if(!deads.contains(upString)){
                        queue.add(upString);
                        deads.add(upString);
                    }
                    c = temp;
                    if( c == '0'){
                        c = '9';
                    }
                    else{
                        c--;
                    }
                    String downString = current.substring(0, i) + c + current.substring(i + 1);
                    if(!deads.contains(downString)){
                        queue.add(downString);
                        deads.add(downString);
                    }
                }
                groupSize = groupSize - 1;
            }
            level = level + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure what might be wrong with your algorithm, looks pretty OK to me, might be something small that needs to be fixed.

Almost the same method, except we'd be using three Sets to solve the problem in Java:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final int openLock(
        final String[] deadends,
        final String target
    ) {
        Set<String> startSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> endSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> deadSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(deadends));
        startSet.add("0000");
        endSet.add(target);
        int minTurns = 0;
        Set<String> tempSet;

        while (!startSet.isEmpty() && !endSet.isEmpty()) {
            if (startSet.size() > endSet.size()) {
                tempSet = startSet;
                startSet = endSet;
                endSet = tempSet;
            }

            tempSet = new HashSet<>();

            for (String start : startSet) {
                if (endSet.contains(start)) {
                    return minTurns;
                }

                if (deadSet.contains(start)) {
                    continue;
                }

                deadSet.add(start);
                StringBuilder startSB = new StringBuilder(start);

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    final char character = startSB.charAt(i);
                    String s1 = startSB.substring(0, i) + (character == '9' ? 0 : character - '0' + 1) + startSB.substring(i + 1);
                    String s2 = startSB.substring(0, i) + (character == '0' ? 9 : character - '0' - 1) + startSB.substring(i + 1);

                    if (!deadSet.contains(s1)) {
                        tempSet.add(s1);
                    }

                    if (!deadSet.contains(s2)) {
                        tempSet.add(s2);
                    }
                }
            }

            minTurns++;
            startSet = tempSet;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

OK! Here is LeetCode's BFS solution, based on which you can figure it out:

```
class Solution {
    public int openLock(String[] deadends, String target) {
        Set<String> dead = new HashSet();
        for (String d: deadends) dead.add(d);

        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList();
        queue.offer("0000");
        queue.offer(null);

        Set<String> seen = new HashSet();
        seen.add("0000");

        int depth = 0;
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            String node = queue.poll();
            if (node == null) {
                depth++;
                if (queue.peek() != null)
                    queue.offer(null);
            } else if (node.equals(target)) {
                return depth;
            } else if (!dead.contains(node)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    for (int d = -1; d <= 1; d += 2) {
                        int y = ((node.charAt(i) - '0') + d + 10) % 10;
                        String nei = node.substring(0, i) + ("" + y) + node.substring(i+1);
                        if (!seen.contains(nei)) {
                            seen.add(nei);
                            queue.offer(nei);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

It seems that they have added new test cases for this problem.

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/open-the-lock/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: thanks again for the assist and help. I found a 90% similar algorithm here - https://leetcode.com/problems/open-the-lock/discuss/703224/Java-BFS. I suspect it is not my BFS rather the way I handle the incrementing and decrementing of characters. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Solution {
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    HashSet<String> deads = new HashSet<String>();
    public int openLock(String[] deadends, String target) {
        for(int i  = 0; i < deadends.length; i++){
            deads.add(deadends[i]);
        }
        if(deads.contains("0000"))return -1;
        int level  = bfs("0000", target);
        return level;
    
    }
public int bfs(String start, String target){
        int level  = 0;
        queue.add(start); // add the start to the queue
        deads.add(start);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            int groupSize = queue.size();
            while(groupSize >0){
                String current = queue.poll();
                if(current.equals(target)) return level;
                for(int i  = 0; i < current.length(); i++){
                    char c = current.charAt(i);
                    char temp  = c;
                    if( c == '9'){
                        c = '0';
                        temp  = c; // THIS LINE IS THE ISSUE. REMOVING IT HELPED!!!!
                    }else{
                        c++;
                    }
                    String upString = current.substring(0, i) + c + current.substring(i + 1);
                    if(!deads.contains(upString)){
                        queue.add(upString);
                        deads.add(upString);
                    }
                    c = temp;
                    if( c == '0'){
                        c = '9';
                    }
                    else{
                        c--;
                    }
                    String downString = current.substring(0, i) + c + current.substring(i + 1);
                    if(!deads.contains(downString)){
                        queue.add(downString);
                        deads.add(downString);
                    }
                }
                groupSize = groupSize - 1;
            }
            level = level + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```